# d3 + positioning data lables in bar chart + top, middle, bottom, center

Tags: html, d3.js, svg

This is my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ygmkvreb/1/), which I am building with from this [example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3885304)

this is the code that I got to add the text labels

```
svg.selectAll(".barText")
      .data(data)                                 
      .enter().append("text")
      .attr("class", "barText")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.letter); })
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.frequency); })
      .text(function(d) { return Math.floor(d.frequency*100)+"%"; });
```

How do I control the position of the label so that it sits:

1. inside the bar
2. on top of the bar
3. the bottom of the bar
4. and always being in the center of the bar

Ideally I don't want it hard coded, just want it dynamic coded.

This is my attempt, but is there a better/other way?

// appears central(of xaxis of bar) but only in this example not sure how dynamic it would be

```
.attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.letter) + x.rangeBand()/5; })
```

//label appears slightly above the bar

```
.attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.frequency) - 10; })
```

---

### **EDIT1**

Might be useful for me to go through [this](https://www.dashingd3js.com/svg-group-element-and-d3js)

here is my code and [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ygmkvreb/5/) to put the rect and text in the 1 group. But not sure how to control the text labels reslative to the bar using this method, other than using the below answer?

```
 //create a bar group for the bar and the labels 
  barGroup = svg.append("g")
                                .attr("class", "barGroup")

  barGroup.selectAll(".bar")
      .data(data)
    .enter().append("rect")
      .attr("class", "bar")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.letter); })
      .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.frequency); })
      .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.frequency); });


barGroup.selectAll(".barText")
      .data(data)                                 
      .enter().append("text")
      .attr("class", "barText")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.letter); })
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.frequency); })
      .text(function(d) { return d.frequency; });
```

Comment: One way to do it is to make your `#bar` a group (`g`) which contains the `rect`and the `text`. Then you can position you labels relative to the bar. You can also use CSS properties such as `text-anchor: middle` for the text to centralize the text horizontally.

Comment: sorry but how, tks

Comment: @helderdarocha  see edit 1, I grouped the rect and the text but not sure what to do after that other than what was answered below?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. inside the bar:
   `.attr("y", function(d) { return Math.min(y(d.frequency) + 10, height); })`
2. on top of the bar:
   `.attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.frequency); })`
3. bottom of the bar: 
   `.attr("y", height)`
4. center of the bar: 
   `.attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.frequency/2); })`

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/ygmkvreb/3/)

to align horizontally, use `text-anchor: middle`, and align text with the bar like so:

`text.barText {
    text-anchor: middle;
}`

`.attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.letter) + x.rangeBand()/2; })`

Comment: tks.by 'inside the bar' I mean at the top of the bar but inside it